# SQLite: Subtract 1st Row from Last Row

Tags: sqlite, query-optimization

I have a large table `data` that has an ascending counter the column `counter` for each row. Assuming that my program is working correctly, `counter` should increase by 20 units per row.

Therefore, for each table the query `Select (Max(counter)-Min(counter))/(Max(ROWID)-1)` should return 20 if the program works correctly. If the program drops any rows, the query would return > 20.

As I **know** that Max and Min are in rows 0 and N, is there a better way to run this search without requiring the processor to search the entire table for the max value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is maintain a table with a single row that keeps a record of the lowest and highest values.

You could maintain this table using [TRIGGER](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)'s.

There would be a small overhead per insert,update,delete due to the triggering but scan for the max/min is not undertaken rather min/max values are calculated based upon the row being inserted/updated/deleted note that deletion takes your *should increase by 20 units per row.* as being a rule that can be applied.

For example, consider, the following demonstration. Noting that it includes an additional (unnecessary) trigger that allows the triggering to be monitored:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS maintable;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS counterlowhigh;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trigger_monitor; /*<<<<<<<<<< ONLY EXISTS TO MONITOR THE TRIGGERING - OTEHREWISE NOT NEEDED */

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS maintable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, counter INTEGER, othercolumns TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS counterlowhigh (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, low INTEGER, high INTEGER);
INSERT INTO counterlowhigh VALUES(1,0,0);
/* ONLY EXISTS TO MONITOR THE TRIGGERING - OTEHREWISE NOT NEEDED */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trigger_monitor (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, timestamp text DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, maintable_id INTEGER, operation TEXT);
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS maintain_counterlowhigh_afterinsert AFTER INSERT ON maintable 
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE counterlowhigh SET low = min(low,new.counter), high = max(high,new.counter) WHERE id = 1;
        /* ONLY EXISTS TO MONITOR THE TRIGGERING - OTEHREWISE NOT NEEDED */
        INSERT INTO trigger_monitor (maintable_id,operation) 
            VALUES (
            new.id,
            'AFTER INSERT counter was '||new.counter
            ||' High='||(SELECT high FROM counterlowhigh WHERE id=1)
            ||' Low='||(SELECT low FROM counterlowhigh WHERE id= 1)
            )
        ;
    END
;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS maintain_counterlowhigh_afterupdate AFTER UPDATE ON maintable
    BEGIN
        UPDATE counterlowhigh SET low = min(low,new.counter), high = max(high,new.counter) WHERE id = 1;
        /* ONLY EXISTS TO MONITOR THE TRIGGERING - OTEHREWISE NOT NEEDED */
        INSERT INTO trigger_monitor (maintable_id,operation) 
            VALUES (
            new.id,
            'AFTER UPDATE counter was '||new.counter
            ||' High='||(SELECT high FROM counterlowhigh WHERE id=1)
            ||' Low='||(SELECT low FROM counterlowhigh WHERE id= 1)
            )
        ;
    END
;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS maintain_counterlowhig_afterdelete AFTER DELETE ON maintable
    BEGIN
        UPDATE counterlowhigh SET low = old.counter + 20 WHERE low = old.counter;
        UPDATE counterlowhigh SET high = old.counter - 20 WHERE high = old.counter;
        /* ONLY EXISTS TO MONITOR THE TRIGGERING - OTEHREWISE NOT NEEDED */
        INSERT INTO trigger_monitor (maintable_id,operation) 
            VALUES (
            old.id,
            'AFTER DELETE counter was '||old.counter
            ||' High='||(SELECT high FROM counterlowhigh WHERE id=1)
            ||' Low='||(SELECT low FROM counterlowhigh WHERE id= 1)
            )
        ;
    END
;

/* Test insertion  */
WITH 
    cte(i) AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT i+1 FROM cte LIMIT 10000)
INSERT INTO maintable (counter,othercolumns) SELECT i * 20,'other data '||i FROM cte
;
/* Show counterhighlow data after insertions */
SELECT * FROM counterlowhigh;
/* Test some deletions */
DELETE FROM maintable WHERE id = 1;
DELETE FROM maintable WHERE id IN (1 /*<<<<< already deleted by previous delete */,53,73,10000,10001) OR id > 10000 /*<<<< should not do anything */;
/* Show counterhighlow data after insertions */
SELECT * FROM counterlowhigh;
```

So initially the counterhighlow table has low and high as 0.
After the 10000 insertions counterhighlow is :-

[image]

After the deletions (the lowest and highest rows being included in the deletions) then counterhighlow is :-

[image]

The trigger monitoring table includes 10004 rows, the first 10000 for the inserts e.g :-

[image]

....

The last 4 rows, the deletions being :-

[image]